# How to inline JS that is required for multiple parts of page layout?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, rendering

- So let's assume that there is an article with multiple photo galleries.
- Photos in each gallery are arranged in a complex grid, which can be built just via JS.
- Size of JS is under ~1KB (gzipped).
- The first gallery is likely above the fold.
- I'm trying to make the page with these galleries load as fast as possible (optimizing the [critical rendering path](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/?hl=en)), and avoid flash of unstyled content (when gallery is unstyled).

Here is where I am now, HTML:

```
<div id="first" class="mygallery">...images markup...</div>
<script>
    /* Inline full JS code required for gallery (~1KB) */
    var gallery = function(id) {
        ...
    };
    gallery('#first');
</script>

<p>Some other content of any length.</p>

<div id="second" class="mygallery">...</div>
<script>
    /* just init gallery using code from the first one */
    gallery('#second');
</script>

<p>Some other content of any length.</p>

<div id="third" class="mygallery">...</div>
<script>
    /* just init gallery using code from the first one */
    gallery('#third');
</script>

etc...
```

My questions:

1. Should I init the gallery directly after its element, or should I init all galleries at once (after the last gallery DOM element, or in `document.ready`)?
2. Should I hide all galleries via `display:none` and then reveal them via JS to avoid FOUC? (for no-js users I can add noscript tag with style  `display:block;`)
3. Should I inline JS at all, isn't ~1KB of gzipped js too much?

Also, should be noted, that when executing `gallery()` method, `getComputedStyle()` is called once (which triggers the layout) and then styles are applied (which triggers paint). Does this affect your answer the the first question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I init the gallery directly after its element, or should I init all galleries at once (after the last gallery DOM element, or in document.ready)?

If the goal is to reduce the amount of work the browser has to do to get pixels on the screen, then it might make sense to init each one progressively and on as-needed basis - e.g. only the first gallery and delay initializing others until a little later.

> Should I hide all galleries via display:none and then reveal them via JS to avoid FOUC? (for no-js users I can add noscript tag with style  display:block;)

For best results reserve the space for the gallery upfront: this minimizes layout reflows and removes that annoying behavior where the page shifts up-and-down as the content loads. For more, see: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/avoid-large-complex-layouts-and-layout-thrashing?hl=en

> Should I inline JS at all, isn't ~1KB of gzipped js too much?

The answer to this depends on a lot of variables. It may be "too much" if it introduces additional RTT's - e.g. exceeds initial 14KB payload allowed by first RTT of a new TCP connection. On the other hand, if that's not a problem then 1KB is fine. Also, consider impact on caching + invalidations -- e.g. do multiple pages use this snippet or just one, how often the snippet needs to change and does that affect cache lifetime of the page that embeds it, etc.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! So at the end I did it like so: I inline the JS code after the first gallery and initialize it. Then, after DOM elements of all other galleries are added, I calculate their position (getComputedStyle() etc.) and apply styles to all at once at the same time to minimize reflows.  When measured via WebPageTest it looks quite fast. Hope that hiding that I'm doing to avoid FOUC doesn't affect SEO of images in gallery...